# Can not pass id to modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Nice to meet you
I am Japanese.
English translation is wonderful.

I want to tell the great Americans.
Now,I would like to ask about the modal window provided by bootestrap.

#### What you want to realize

I want to pass the value of micropost.user_id to the modal window.

【micropost】

```
<%= micropost.user_id %> →1
```

【modal window】

```
<%= micropost.user_id %> →1
```

#### Export

As shown in the figure above, the id that should have passed will change (all will be 3).

#### Execution procedure

①Insert id into data
②Pass id in modal window with javascript.
③Display id acquired in modal window.

#### Expected results

In this case, 1 is displayed in the modal window.

#### Actual result

3 is displayed in the modal window.
(3 is the login user's id.)

#### Step description

②Pass id in modal window with javascript.
I think this is a problem.

The data of the character string is the same as that of the one sent and the one received.

#### Source

**【_micropost.html.erb】**

```
<%= micropost.user_id %>→1
<% @id = micropost.user_id %>→1
<%= @id %>→1
```

**【_micropost.html.erb】①Insert id into data②Pass id in modal window with javascript.**

```
<div class="micropost-line" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"
    data-user_name= "<%= username(micropost.user) %>" data-user_content="<%= content(micropost.title, micropost.content)%>" 
    data-user_time="<%= time_ago_in_words(micropost.created_at) %>" ★data-user_data="<% @id %>">★
```

**【_micropost.html.erb】③Display id acquired in modal window.**

```
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="modal-micropost-content"></div>
     <div class="modal-micropost-time"></div>
    Modalcontent
        <div class="micropost-option">
            <%= current_user.id %> →3★
            <%= @id %> →3(Expect 1)★
            <% if current_user.id == @id %>
            <%= user_delete(micropost.user, micropost) %>
            <% end %>
        </div>
     ・
     ・
   </div>

<script>
    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
        var user_name = button.data('user_name');
        var user_content = button.data('user_content');
        var user_time = button.data('user_time');
        var user_data = button.data('user_data');
        var modal = $(this);
        modal.find('.modal-title').text(user_name);
        modal.find('.modal-body .modal-micropost-content').text(user_content);
        modal.find('.modal-body .modal-micropost-time').text(user_time);
        modal.find('.modal-body .modal-micropost-option').data(user_data);
    });
</script>
```

#### Environment

rails 4.2.5
bootstrap-sass (3.3.7, 3.2.0.0)

Thank you for seeing my post.

### Additional Information

【html】

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal タイトル</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="modal-micropost-content"></div>
         <div class="modal-micropost-time"></div>
        Modal内容
            <!-- User 削除リンク -->
            <div class="micropost-option">
                3
                3
                3
                </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">閉じる</button>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




<script>
    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
        var user_name = button.data('user_name');
        var user_content = button.data('user_content');
        var user_time = button.data('user_time');
        var user_data = button.data('user_data');
        var modal = $(this);
        modal.find('.modal-title').text(user_name);
        modal.find('.modal-body .modal-micropost-content').text(user_content);
        modal.find('.modal-body .modal-micropost-time').text(user_time);
        modal.find('.modal-body .micropost-option').data(user_data);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Do you mind describing your question?

Comment: Aren't you missing an equal sign ? `★data-user_data="<% @id %>">` shouldn't be `★data-user_data="<%= @id %>">` ?

Comment: I intended to keep in mind.
Sorry for all mistakes.

Comment: "=" was added, but the result did not change....

Comment: Well, have you posted your issue also in http://ja.stackoverflow.com/ ? You may solve your problem quicker there. You should paste your output code: in chrome, open the page, right click, select Inspect, then click on the <html> element at the top of the code, Ctrl-C and paste the code in the post.

Comment: Thank you very much.
Ja.stackoverflow.com is hard to answer. I decided to use this site at the recommendation of my friend. Relatively, I heard that you can receive answers and advice from everyone.